# Copying Range to PPT including Data Validation Loop - Pivot Charts not updating during process

Tags: excel, vba, loops, powerpoint

I have an Excel worksheet that updates a number of charts and tables based on a data validation list.
I have the following code that loops through the validated list, copies the selected range, and posts to a new PowerPoint.

Charts that are fed off of pivot tables are not updating throughout this copy & paste process.

Could anyone offer some guidance?
I have tried putting in a 'wait' function, as well as others, such as

```
Application.Calculate
If Not Application.CalculationState = xlDone Then
    DoEvents
End If
```

To no avail.
Here is the current code:
(Edited to include looping function but still creates separate PPTs)

```
       Sub Loop_Through_List()

    Dim cell                  As Excel.Range
    Dim rgDV                  As Excel.Range
    Dim DV_Cell               As Excel.Range

Dim rng As Range
Dim PowerPointApp As Object
Dim myPresentation As Object
Dim mySlide As Object
Dim myShape As Object
Dim pvtTbl As PivotTable

'Create an Instance of PowerPoint
  On Error Resume Next

    'Is PowerPoint already opened?
      Set PowerPointApp = GetObject(class:="PowerPoint.Application")

    'Clear the error between errors
      Err.Clear

    'If PowerPoint is not already open then open PowerPoint
      If PowerPointApp Is Nothing Then Set PowerPointApp = CreateObject(class:="PowerPoint.Application")

    'Handle if the PowerPoint Application is not found
      If Err.Number = 429 Then
        MsgBox "PowerPoint could not be found, aborting."
        Exit Sub
      End If

  On Error GoTo 0

'Optimize Code
  Application.ScreenUpdating = False

'Create a New Presentation
  Set myPresentation = PowerPointApp.Presentations.Add

      'Add a slide to the Presentation
  Set mySlide = myPresentation.Slides.Add(1, 12) '12 = ppLayoutBLANK

Set DV_Cell = Range("A2")
Worksheets("Main Tab - Comp").Calculate
    Set rgDV = Application.Range(Mid$(DV_Cell.Validation.Formula1, 2))
    For Each cell In rgDV.Cells
        DV_Cell.Value = cell.Value


              'Add a slide to the Presentation
  Set mySlide = myPresentation.Slides.Add(1, 12)   '12 = ppLayoutBLANK

 'Copy Range from Excel
  Set rng = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("A3:AA52")

'Copy Excel Range
  rng.Copy

'Paste to PowerPoint and position
  mySlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial DataType:=2  '2 = ppPasteEnhancedMetafile
  Set myShape = mySlide.Shapes(mySlide.Shapes.Count)

'Set position:
      myShape.Left = 0
      myShape.Top = 0

'Make PowerPoint Visible and Active
  PowerPointApp.Visible = True
  PowerPointApp.Activate

'Clear The Clipboard
  Application.CutCopyMode = False

  Next
End Sub
```

Comment: you need to create the instance of powerpoint , then a new presentation, then a loop which transfers data to slides. Now you may need to add slides, or if you have a known number of slides you could either add these as an array of slides ( i think) in one go or use a template, and open that. You can target slides by their index. You can also name slides and reference them by those names. Outside of the loop, you then need to finish with the presentation (Save and close?) and quite the powerpoint application so it doesn't keep running.

Comment: https://chandoo.org/wp/2011/08/03/create-powerpoint-presentations-using-excel-vba/ and https://www.thespreadsheetguru.com/blog/2014/3/17/copy-paste-an-excel-range-into-powerpoint-with-vba    There are so many resources out there for this.

Comment: And this, from Microsoft help, does exactly what you want to do in terms of looping transfer....[VBA Help - Loop to Copy from Excel to PowerPoint](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/msoffice_powerpoint-msoffice_custom-mso_2013_release/vba-help-loop-to-copy-from-excel-to-powerpoint/8ee91478-1c11-4f02-bac8-055e42cdc40f)

Comment: @QHarr thank you very much for your help. with it, I have found a loop function that will cycle through the items. I have edited the original to match. Could you offer your thoughts on how to create a new slide each time rather than a new PPT?

Comment: I am going to work on in for a couple hours and see can I solve it. I am not educated in VBA, have just been trying to pick it up to help my job. Thank you for your help though - I appreciate it.

Comment: This is my first time using the site and it is recommending that I do not post too many comments.   I have worked on this problem all day and have made some progress. Now I have gotten closer to the correct function. As is always the case with VBA, now there is a new problem. I have edited the post above to reflect

Answer (score 1):

Ok. So this isn't the panacea you might be hoping for. My aim here is to take your code, go through some changes to it, discuss some general ideas/principles, to hopefully help you structure your own solution.

Other users may wish to chip in to make this more useful to solving your task.
The problem was that there is a lot to address and much of it is really more suited for a code review.

**Task:**

You want to loop a range of cells and repeatedly copy an updated range from Excel to a new slide in a powerpoint presentation.

**Problem:**

You are creating repeated instances of powerpoint and new powerpoint presentations instead of copying ranges to new slides within the same presentation.

**Required (pseudo code) process:**

1. Create the powerpoint application or grab an existing one
2. Set this presentation to a variable you can then reference
3. Loop your Excel range copying the range each time across to a newly added slide in the presentation
4. Save changes to presentation and close (optional)
5. Close powerpoint (optional but needs to happen at some point so isn't left hanging in the background)

That is basically the process. You would want error handling etc but that is beyond the scope of what I intend to put here.

First things first....

### **Code explanation:**

**0) [Option Explicit](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/language-reference-vba/articles/option-explicit-statement)**

Put this at the top of your code. It forces explicit declaration of all variables and finds typos in their use etc. If you want it always [on](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/statements/option-explicit-statement), you can go Solution Explorer > select a project > Project >Properties > Compile tab.

**1) Scope**

The scope of your procedure is implicitly public so let us make this explicit:

```
Public Sub Loop_Through_List()
```

**2)  Optimization**

You want to optimize with your `ScreenUpdating` at the top of your code. No-one wants the screen flicker at the start until you switch off the screen-updating. And remember to switch it back **on** at the end!

Be careful of optimization that switches off calculation if you are relying on calculated values for your range pastes.

```
Public Sub Loop_Through_List()      

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
```

**3)  Variables and declarations**

Your "wall of declarations":

```
Dim cell                  As Excel.Range
Dim rgDV                  As Excel.Range
Dim DV_Cell               As Excel.Range  
Dim rng As Range
Dim PowerPointApp As Object
Dim myPresentation As Object
Dim mySlide As Object
Dim myShape As Object
Dim pvtTbl As PivotTable
```

We can chip away at this wall:

**a)** Variables can be declared as close as possible to their actual use. This makes the code easier to read. See the full code for an idea of how this can be implemented.

**b)** `Dim cell As Excel.Range` - not sure what the official line is on this, but as the code is running in Excel, if you fully qualify your ranges, I think you can drop the Excel i.e. just `Dim cell As Excel.Range`.

**Except,**

**c)** Give your variables meaningful names, that won't cause confusion i.e. not `cell`, and are not reserved [keywords](https://bettersolutions.com/vba/syntax/keywords.htm), e.g. `Call`, that the compiler uses to determine the structure of your code

So something meaningful, when the object represents that you are iterating of a range of cells, might be:

```
Dim currentCell  As Range
```

And as characters aren't costing you anything you could generously extend

```
DV_Cell  to DataValidationCell
```

And I, personally, also avoid "_" in variable names if possible.

There are lots of resources online advising on naming conventions including avoiding Hungarian notation and the correct case to use. One example is [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa240858(v=vs.60).aspx).

**d)** [Late binding versus early binding](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/245115/using-early-binding-and-late-binding-in-automation).  You are using late binding when 
you say

```
Dim myPresentation As Object
```

This is good when distributing code and you don't know what version of an application your user has.

You can also use early binding, especially for development, as  it compiles quickly and offers intellisense on the current object i.e. pops up the associated list of properties/methods as you type.

Early binding for the same would be:

```
Dim myPresentation As Presentation
```

**e)** Remove unused variables

It may be that you haven't included all the code but currently there is no `pvtTbl` , so this line, `Dim pvtTbl As PivotTable`, can go.

**f)** Use variables to hold objects and fully qualify objects.

It makes code easier to read and ensures you are working with the expected object.

So doing this:

```
Dim targetBook As Workbook
Dim wsMain As Worksheet

Set targetBook = ThisWorkbook
Set wsMain = targetBook.Worksheets("Main Tab - Comp")
```

Means lines like the following:

```
Set DV_Cell = Range("A2")
Worksheets("Main Tab - Comp").Calculate
```

Becomes clear and specific

```
 Set DV_Cell = wsMain.Range("A2")  
 wsMain.Calculate
```

Note: I had to assume you meant Main tab for `DV_Cell` due to the lack of specificity in your original post.

And this:

`Set rng = ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range("A3:AA52")`

I am not clear whether `ThisWorkbook.ActiveSheet` is `wsMain` but be sure to use actual sheet name. I have re-written as:

```
Set rng = wsMain.Range("A3:AA52")
```

**4)  Code ordering**

Make sure the code flow follows the pseudo code process I described at the start. Or, in your own process, try writing out the psuedo code process, sense-checking that, and then making sure your code matches.

An example is:

```
Worksheets("Main Tab - Comp").Calculate
```

Which I have re-written as:

```
wsMain.Calculate
```

I have put this inside the loop as I think you want to refresh calculations based on a change to  `DV_Cell`'s value; that changes within the loop.

**5) Modular code and single responsibility principle**

It is a common practice to modularize your code. Have one sub/function do one thing. I have included an example here, Function `GetPPT`, of how you could pull out the getting of the presentation.

To quote from [RubberDuck OOP VBA Part1 Debunking Stuff](https://rubberduckvba.wordpress.com/2016/06/16/oop-vba-pt-1-debunking-stuff/)

> The Single Responsibility Principle is a golden rule that’s as hard to
>   follow in VBA as it is in any other language: write small procedures
>   and functions that do one thing, prefer many small specialized modules
>   over fewer, large ones.

There is a lot more in that article to look at.

**6) Slide index**

In the line below, the 1 is the [slide index](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/powerpoint-vba/articles/slides-addslide-method-powerpoint)

```
 Set mySlide = myPresentation.Slides.Add(1, 12)
```

If you want to target different slides you would want to use a different index.

**7) Default properties**

`DV_Cell.Value = currentCell.Value`    can become

`DV_Cell = currentCell`

`.Value` is the default property of the Range object. You can specify 
`currentCell.Value` or shorten to just `currentCell`

**8) Incremented object references** (sounds fancy!)

In relation to my slide index comment earlier. Increment the slide where you are pasting and the shape.

```
Set mySlide = .Slides.Add(.Slides.Count + 1, 12)
Set myShape = mySlide.Shapes(mySlide.Shapes.Count)
```

**9) Next Control variables in loops**

Where you have ,

`Next`

, name the iterator explicitly i.e.

```
Next currentCell
```

With multiple loops, in particular, this makes reading things a lot easier.

**1O) Avoiding creating multiple powerpoints/applications**

In addition to making sure you create the application and new presentation outside of the copy loop, ensure closing/quit of presentation and powerpoint application are outside of copying ranges loop.

**11) Saving presentation**

Depending on whether presentation already existed, or if you created a new presentation, you will need code to specify saving your changed file.

**12) Freeing up resources**

Remember to get rid of the powerpoint application when done.

```
.Quit
```

**Example, not perfect, code:**

```
Option Explicit

Public Sub Loop_Through_List()                   'You can add a reference to MS Powerpoint in tools references to take advantage of faster early binding and intellisense

    'Optimize Code
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False           'optimization at start

    Dim PowerPointApp As PowerPoint.Application  'Object

    Set PowerPointApp = GetPPT                   'We now have a powerpoint presenation

    Dim myPresentation As Presentation           'Object
    Dim mySlide As Slide                         'Object
    Dim myShape As PowerPoint.Shape              'Object

    'Create a New Presentation
    Set myPresentation = PowerPointApp.Presentations.Add

    'Add a slide to the Presentation
    Set mySlide = myPresentation.Slides.Add(1, 12) '12 = ppLayoutBLANK

    Dim targetBook As Workbook
    Dim wsMain As Worksheet

    Set targetBook = ThisWorkbook
    Set wsMain = targetBook.Worksheets("Main Tab - Comp")

    Dim currentCell  As Range                         'currentCell as range
    Dim rgDV  As Range
    Dim DV_Cell As Range                         'Excel.range not sure Excel is needed here
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim pvtTbl As PivotTable 'Where is this used?

    Set DV_Cell = wsMain.Range("A2")

    '********Note: this is an alternative for testing ***************

     'Set rgDV = Application.Range(Mid$(DV_Cell.Validation.Formula1, 2)) 'so this returns a cell reference

     Set rgDV = wsMain.Range("B2:B4")

    '***************************************************************

    For Each currentCell In rgDV.Cells
        Debug.Print currentCell.Address
        DV_Cell = currentCell

        wsMain.Calculate     'Assume you now want a recalculation based on changing DV_Cell

        With myPresentation

            'Copy Range from Excel
            Set rng = wsMain.Range("A3:AA52")

            'Copy Excel Range
            rng.Copy

            Set mySlide = .Slides.Add(.Slides.Count + 1, 12) '12 = ppLayoutBLANK. The first number is the index

            'Paste to PowerPoint and position
            mySlide.Shapes.PasteSpecial DataType:=2 '2 = ppPasteEnhancedMetafile
            Set myShape = mySlide.Shapes(mySlide.Shapes.Count)

            'Set position:
            myShape.Left = 0
            myShape.Top = 0

        End With

        'Clear The Clipboard
        Application.CutCopyMode = False

    Next currentCell

    'Presentation Save code goes here. Depending on whether presentation already existed or you created a new presentation

    'closing/quiting code

    PowerPointApp.Quit

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub

Private Function GetPPT() As Object

    Dim PowerPointApp As Object
    'Create an Instance of PowerPoint
    On Error Resume Next

    'Is PowerPoint already opened?
    Set PowerPointApp = GetObject(class:="PowerPoint.Application")

    'Clear the error between errors
    Err.Clear

    'If PowerPoint is not already open then open PowerPoint
    If PowerPointApp Is Nothing Then
        Set PowerPointApp = CreateObject(class:="PowerPoint.Application")
        PowerPointApp.Visible = True
    End If

    On Error GoTo 0

    Set GetPPT = PowerPointApp

End Function
```

Comment: Wow, that is brilliant. I got a version working last night but as I'm sure you can imagine, it is littered with issues. Yours' looks much more structured. I will work on this version over the weekend and send you an update. Thank you for giving your time to help out, I enjoy learning about it.

Comment: Hope it helps :-)